# I don't understand this sequenced calling of static methods in Snackbar class. Can someone explain it? Thanks

Tags: android-snackbar

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

how does the above code works?

Answer (score 0):

The `Snackbar` class has a static method `make` that takes 3 parameters (view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG). I don't know what view is but the 2nd is a string and the third is a final variable defined in Snackbar (most probably a long value).

The method `make` returns a object which has a method called `setAction` which has two parameters ("Action", null) The first parameter is a String and the 2nd could be any type of object.

The method `setAction` returns a new object which has a method `show()` which may return a new value but can also be void.